# BFS to solve openLock

Tags: python

Leetcode introduced two  [BFS-Template](https://leetcode.com/explore/learn/card/queue-stack/231/practical-application-queue/1372/), the second:

```py
#Return the length of the shortest path between root and target node.
#the pseudocode 
def bfs(root, target) 
    #declare data
    queue = deque()  # store all nodes which are waiting to be processed
    visited = set() # store all the nodes that we've visited
    #step to monitro the implemantions
    step = 0;       # number of steps neeeded from root to current node
    # initialize
    add root to queue
    add root to visited;
    # BFS
    while (queue is not empty) {
        step = step + 1;
        # iterate the nodes which are already in the queue
        size = len(queue); 
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
            Node cur = the first node in queue; 
            return step if cur is target; 
            for (Node next : the neighbors of cur) #stretch .
                if (next is not in used) #
                    add next to queue;
                    add next to visited;
            remove the first node from queue; #
    return -1;           #failure
```

The template is clear because it do one thing at one time,
1)do `terminating check` in `Node cur = the first node in queue`;
2)stretch to find neighbors in the following iterations .
In contrast, many implementation check `if next == target, return step +1`  at the current level' which mixed the terminating checking and stretch job.

Employ the template to solve the `openLock` problem

> You have a lock in front of you with 4 circular wheels. Each wheel has 10 slots: `'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'`. The wheels can rotate freely and wrap around: for example we can turn `'9'` to be `'0'`, or `'0'` to be `'9'`. Each move consists of turning one wheel one slot.
>
> The lock initially starts at `'0000'`, a string representing the state of the 4 wheels.
>
> You are given a list of `deadends` dead ends, meaning if the lock displays any of these codes, the wheels of the lock will stop turning and you will be unable to open it.
>
> Given a `target` representing the value of the wheels that will unlock the lock, return the minimum total number of turns required to open the lock, or -1 if it is impossible.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```py
> Input: deadends = ["0201","0101","0102","1212","2002"], target = "0202"
> Output: 6
> Explanation:
> A sequence of valid moves would be "0000" -> "1000" -> "1100" -> "1200" -> "1201" -> "1202" -> "0202".
> Note that a sequence like "0000" -> "0001" -> "0002" -> "0102" -> "0202" would be invalid,
> because the wheels of the lock become stuck after the display becomes the dead end "0102".
> ```

My Solution

```py
class Solution5:
    def openLock(self, deadends, target):
        from collections import deque
        #declare 
        queue = deque()
        visited = set()
        root = '0000'
        #initiate 
        step = 0
        deads = set(deadends)
        queue.append(root)
        visited.add(root)

        if root in deads: return -1 #fast fail

        while queue: 
            step += 1  
            size = len(queue)  

            for i in range(size):
                cur = queue.popleft()
                #logging.debug(f"cur: {cur}, step: {step}")
                if cur == target: return step 
                #collect the next node.
                #stretch and add next to queue
                for i in range(0, 4):
                    for j in [-1, 1]: 
                        nxt = cur[:i] + str((int(cur[i]) + j + 10) % 10) + cur[i+1:]
                        if (nxt not in deads) and  (nxt not in visited): 
                            queue.append(nxt)
                            visited.add(nxt)
        return -1 #failure case
```

Test with case:

```py
    def test_b(self):
        deadends = ["8888"] #0000-> 0009 one step 
        target = "0009"
        answer = 1
        check = self.solution.openLock(deadends, target)
        self.assertEqual(answer, check)
```

Unfortunately, it report error

```py
base) 10:48AM 15/04 Monday:me@host:~/Documents/Programs/Algorithms:
$ python 752.OpenTheLock.py  MyCase.test_b
DEBUG cur: 0000, step: 1
DEBUG cur: 9000, step: 2
DEBUG cur: 1000, step: 2
DEBUG cur: 0900, step: 2
DEBUG cur: 0100, step: 2
DEBUG cur: 0090, step: 2
DEBUG cur: 0010, step: 2
DEBUG cur: 0009, step: 2
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_b (__main__.MyCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "752.OpenTheLock.py", line 184, in test_b
    self.assertEqual(answer, check)
AssertionError: 1 != 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Have to re-initiate `step = -1`

```py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.750s

OK
```

the java and C++ implementations of templeate II used pre-increment `++step`,

So, does check root is regarded as step 0?
`step = -1` is the appropriate initiation in python's implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question:

> does check root is regarded as step 0?
>   step = -1 is the appropriate initiation in python's implementation?

yes, we should use `step = -1` here, because the first element in queue is `0000`, it is not count in result, so we should decrease `step` to `-1`.

---

For question:

> "In contrast, many implementation check `if next == target, return step +1` at the current level' which mixed the terminating checking and stretch job."

It is a method to stop early, because we already know it will not pass the teminating check in recursion, so we just don't enter it, and prune it. It will decrease one recursion depth.

But as you said, in many situations, this implemenation is not recommended, because it will mixed the terminating checking and stretch job.